# Adding aspects on services across OSGi bundles

Tags: java, spring, osgi, spring-aop, apache-felix

I have an OSGi bundle (that is not owned by me - so I cannot change it!) that exposes (exports) a service `EchoService`, and I want to attach an aspect to  methods of this service (so as to perform some pre/post processing around it). These are deployed on the Apache Felix container.

I've written my own OSGi bundle (that obviously imports the `EchoService`), and attaches Spring aspects to it using standard Spring AOP. However, looks like the aspects are not attached and my interceptor is not being invoked.

I suspect that this is because I'm trying to intercept a service that does not belong to my bundle (which seems reasonable). Is that correct? How can I overcome this?

Here's what my interceptor/aspect looks like:

```
    @Before("serviceOperation()")
    public void before(JoinPoint jp) {
        logger.debug("Entering method: " + jp.toShortString());
    }

    @AfterReturning("serviceOperation()")
    public void after(JoinPoint jp) {       
        logger.debug("Exiting method: " + jp.toShortString());      
    }
```

Comment: I guess you have to give us more details about your runtime environment and what kinds of aspects you are trying to create.

Comment: "details about your runtime environment" - could you please elaborate what exact details are you looking for. And for the "kind of aspects",  I've added the interceptor snippets above.

Comment: How do you combine spring and OSGi? Which osgi framework? Is it a standalone app, or does it run in a container? Which container? Are you using pure Spring aspects or in combination with ApsectJ load time weaving?

Comment: We are using spring blueprint on Apache Felix container. Pure spring aspects.

Comment: Hi Saket...I am in a similar situation.. My advice is not executed...Eclipse compiled pointcuts to verify:"`Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch` wasn't seen...VM arguments: `-Dosgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj` and also tried `-Dosgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hooks`

Comment: I also have aop.xml in META-INF that has following `<weaver>` options configured : `<weaver options="-verbose -Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true -Xset:weaveJavaPackages=true"></weaver>` ....any ideas if you have gotten this resolved....thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an AOP nor a Spring expert, but maybe I could give you some ideas. As far as I see [Spring use standard J2SE dynamic proxies for AOP proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/ch07.html#aop-introduction-proxies). Hence your clients [should use the proxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/ch07s06.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) instead of the original `EchoService` object. This is also true when you're using CGLIB proxies because ["the proxies are created by sub-classing the actual class"](http://insufficientinformation.blogspot.com/2007/12/spring-dynamic-proxies-vs-cglib-proxies.html).

If your client bundles asking for an `EchoService` you have to pass them the proxy somehow. For this inside an OSGi container you should also export an `EchoService` (proxy) and make sure that the clients use the proxied service/bundle, not the original. You can accomplish this by setting a different version number for the (proxied) package and set this version as an import requirement in your client bundles. (I suppose you can modify the clients of `EchoService`.) For services you can set a property when you're registering it and modify the clients to query only for services which have this property.

If you are not able to modify the client bundles another solution could be wrapping the original bundle as an internal jar in your bundle. You can call the wrapped bundle's activator from your activator and pass them a modified `BundleContext`. This `BundleContext` should catch the registering service calls and register the proxy object instead of the original `EchoService`. You can use simple delegate pattern since `BundleContext`, `ServiceListener` etc. are usually interfaces. I suppose it could work but it maybe has other challenges.